# Different fragment shader colors

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glew

I want to draw different figures with different colors using shaders.

I tried using uniform variables and using vertex attributes of the meshes to separate Vertex Buffer Objects but when I run the program only the second color is used and the first figure isn't shown at all. Im not sure if it's an issue with how I bind the shaders or with the way I use uniform variables. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const char* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
"}\0";

const char* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"in vec4 color;\n"
"out vec4 FragColor;\n"
"uniform vec3 figColor;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   FragColor = vec4(figColor, 0.0f);\n"
"}\n\0";

// Set of vertices that draw the different figures:
float vertices1[] = { 
    -0.8f, 0.6f, 0.0f, 
    -0.8f, 0.4f, 0.0f,
    -0.83f, 0.44f, 0.0f,
    -0.87f, 0.51f, 0.0f,
    -0.9f, 0.57f, 0.0f,
    -0.93f, 0.63f, 0.0f,
    -0.95f, 0.69f, 0.0f,
    -0.97f, 0.75f, 0.0f,
    -0.98f, 0.8f, 0.0f,
    -0.91f, 0.8f, 0.0f,
    -0.85f, 0.79f, 0.0f,
    -0.8f, 0.77f, 0.0f,
};

float vertices2[] = {
    -0.8f, -0.15f, 0.0f, 
    -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.95f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.86f, -0.01f, 0.0f,
    -0.81f, -0.02f, 0.0f,
    -0.75f, -0.03f, 0.0f,
};

GLuint vertexShader;
GLuint fragmentShader;
GLuint shaderProgram;

void display(void) {
    // Background color.
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    GLint uniform = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "figColor");
    glUniform3f(uniform, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 12);
    glUniform3f(uniform, 0.0f, 0.749f, 1.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);
    glUseProgram(0);

    glFlush();
}

// Main.
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    // Color mode.
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
    // Window size.
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    // Title.
    glutCreateWindow("Tarea 3: Figura con curvas");
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (err != GLEW_OK) {
        printf("glewInit failed: %s", glewGetErrorString(err));
        exit(1);
    }

    // Compile vertex shader.
    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    // Check for vertex shader compilation errors.   
    int success;
    char infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n");
    }

    // Compile fragment shader.
    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    // Check for fragment shader compile errors.  
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n");
    }

    // Link and delete shaders.
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    //Separating the Vertex Buffer Objects.
    GLuint VBOs[2];
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices1), vertices1, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices2), vertices2, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Specify a VertexArrayObject for each mesh.
    GLuint VAOs[2];
    glGenVertexArrays(2, VAOs);

    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[0]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs[0]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[1]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs[1]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // Bind the VAO before the draw call.
    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[0]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 12);

    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[1]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 24);

    // Displaying the figures.
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: It's a typo. The fragment shader doesn't compile, there is missing a semicolon after `uniform vec3 figColor`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I just added the semicolon but I'm still having trouble with the first figure and the first color, they aren't appearing on my screen. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to generate the vertex buffer object names:

```
//Separating the Vertex Buffer Objects.
GLuint VBOs[2];
glGenBuffers(2, VBOs); <----
```

You have to bind the vertex array before drawing the mesh in the main loop:

```cpp
GLuint VAOs[2];

void display(void) {
    // Background color.
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    GLint uniform = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "figColor");
    
    glUniform3f(uniform, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[0]);                     // <---
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 12);
    
    glUniform3f(uniform, 0.0f, 0.749f, 1.0f);
    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[1]);                     // <----
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);
    glUseProgram(0);

    glFlush();
}
```

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // [...]

    // Specify a VertexArrayObject for each mesh.
    // GLuint VAOs[2]; <---- DELETE
    glGenVertexArrays(2, VAOs);

    // [...]

    // DELETE
    /*
    // Bind the VAO before the draw call.
    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[0]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 12);

    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[1]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 24);
    */

    // [...]
```